# Getting an error "A non-serializable value was detected in the state" when using redux toolkit - but NOT with normal redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to switch an app I am building over to use Redux Toolkit, and have noticed this error coming up as soon as I switched over to configureStore from createStore:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `varietals.red.0`. Value:, Varietal {
  "color": "red",
  "id": "2ada6486-b0b5-520e-b6ac-b91da6f1b901",
  "isCommon": true,
  "isSelected": false,
  "varietal": "bordeaux blend",
}, 
Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: TOGGLE_VARIETAL.
(See https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state)
```

After poking around I found the issue seems to be with my custom models. For example the varietals array is created from a varietal model:

```
class Varietal {
  constructor(id, color, varietal, isSelected, isCommon) {
  this.id = id;
  this.color = color;
  this.varietal = varietal;
  this.isSelected = isSelected;
  this.isCommon = isCommon;
 }
}
```

and using that I map over an array of strings to create my Varietal array which goes into my state:

```
// my utility function for creating the array
const createVarietalArray = (arr, color, isCommon) =>
  arr.map(v => new Varietal(uuidv5(v, NAMESPACE), color, v, false, isCommon));';

// my array of strings
import redVarietals from '../constants/varietals/red';

// the final array to be exported and used in my state
export const COMMON_RED = createVarietalArray(redVarietals.common.sort(), 'red', true);
```

When I switched out the model and replaced the array creating utility with something that returned a plain array of objects like this:

```
export const createVarietalArray = (arr, color, isCommon) =>
  arr.map(v => ({
    id: uuidv5(v, NAMESPACE),
    color,
    varietal: v,
    isSelected: false,
    isCommon,
  }));
```

then that got the error to go away for that PARTICULAR reducer, however I have these custom models all through my app and before I start ripping them all out and recoding them simply to be able to use the Redux Toolkit I wanted to ask here if that is REALLY what the issue is before I did that...

Comment: In my case, I was passing a full network response to redux instead of response.data

Answer (score 180):

This is more likely a problem from `redux-persist`. `redux-toolkit` provide few default middleware within it's `getDefaultMiddleware`

```
import { getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
```

You can disable each middleware by providing false flag. To remove `serializableCheck`

```
const customizedMiddleware = getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: false
})
```

For details check `redux-toolkit` [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20goals%20of,checks%20for%20two%20common%20issues%3A&text=(Forked%20from%20redux%2Dimmutable%2Dstate%2Dinvariant%20.)).

**[2021/10/07] edit**:

To learn more about why this error happens, and why setting `serializableCheck` to false fixes it, read [Working with Non-Serializable Data | Usage Guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data) redux toolkit docs.

Additionally, the `getDefaultMiddleware` export is being deprecated in favor of using a callback form. See [Future planning: RTK 2.0? · Issue #958 · reduxjs/redux-toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/958#issuecomment-875538589) and [getDefaultMiddleware deprecated · Issue #1324 · reduxjs/redux-toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1324) to learn more about why.

As to what it's being replaced with, see the [getDefaultMiddleware | Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) documentation to learn more:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import rootReducer from './reducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(),
})
```

Comment: Anyone seeing this and working with redux-persist, do not entirely disable the serializable check unless you know what you're doing. It's better to specifically disable the actions from redux-persist. [See the answer from @AmerllicA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62610422/5026438)

Comment: In my case it is probably caused by `redux-saga`: 
`A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `type`. 
Value: ƒ actionCreator() {
  var args = [];
  for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
    args[_i] = arguments[_i];
  }
  if (prepareAction) `

Option above suppressed the error but I don't think it is correct workaround.

Comment: getDefaultMiddleware is now deprecated, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68509710/10765649 from boluwatife-fakorede

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @DakoJunior, edited the answer to include links to why it's being deprecated, and how to use the new callback syntax.

Comment: Is it ok to put instances of AbortController in the redux store?

Comment: If someone is encountering this issue in the context of redux-persist, this is how you do it: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist

Answer (score 86):

Yes. [We've always told Redux users they *should not* put non-serializable values in the store](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).  Redux Toolkit was specifically designed to help provide good defaults when setting up a Redux store, and as part of that, it includes checks to make sure you're not accidentally mutating your data and that you're not including non-serializable values.

Class instances are by definition not fully serializable, so it's correctly flagging those instances as a problem.  Please rewrite your logic to *not* pass those in to the store.

In general, React and Redux apps should be written using *only* plain JS objects and arrays as data.  You don't need "model classes".

Comment: Um. I have no idea why you felt the need to drop this comment, on an answer I wrote a year ago.  Ultimately it's _your_ codebase, and you can do whatever you want with it. But as a general rule, React ecosystem apps don't use model classes, and Redux _has_ always been very opinionated about not allowing classes in the Redux store state.  So, that's the advice we give to people.

Comment: Wouldn't be nice to add a way to control the serialization and thus allowing to store every value type we want and/or need?

Comment: You can [customize the behavior of the serialization check middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware) if desired, including overriding the "what values are serializable?" callback or turning it off entirely. However, we **strongly recommend that you do not do that**. Ultimately it's your app and you can do whatever you want, but these guidelines exist for a reason.

Comment: Thanks! Already seen this, and thought it wasn't what I need: I expected to find a way to convert my classes to/from string. Am I missing something?

Comment: Uh... no, we don't do any serialization of values ourselves. Redux state is ultimately "just" a normal JS variable. But, viewing Redux state via the DevTools requires that the state be serialized out to the extension, and cases like persistence require the state to be serialized as well. Additionally, storing class instances implies mutable state updates, which are not allowed in Redux. So, we're trying to block people from making that sort of mistake. I'd strongly suggest that you try to find a different approach to working with your data in Redux.

Comment: And given a large (I mean very large) set of typescript classes already in place that we want to use as state and that have many properties of Date type, which approach would you recommend?

Comment: In all honesty, in that case you may not want to use Redux :)

Comment: To add to what Mark said regarding how to solve this by overriding Redux's serialization behavior, the Redux Toolkit docs on _Working with Non-Serializable Data_ are a great read that further explains why this issue happens, and how to apply a fix to the specific part of your redux application that is causing it: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data

Comment: JavaScript "Set" is still not recognized and shows this warning all the time. I think we can now extend this to include Set and other new data structures apart from arrays.

Comment: Correct. `Map`, `Set`, `Date`, and classes are all considered "non-serializable values" by default.

Comment: @markerikson Thank you, i don't understand until now why i got this error! and because of the explanation you wrote, now i understand very well! so thx.

Answer (score 84):

With the `getDefaultMiddleware` getting depreciated, this can be resolved by using

```
   middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
```

Comment: Can we do this serializableCheck false for only one reducer?

Comment: This works, however, what happens If I make it `serializableCheck: false,`

Answer (score 53):

I faced this issue on `React Native` when I wanted to implement `redux-persist` alongside `@reduxjs/toolkit`, and I got this error:

[image]

Then I fixed it by following code:

```js
import {
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  getDefaultMiddleware,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'utils/storage'; // in fact it is AsyncStorage
import counter from 'reduxStore/reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
  counter,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    },
  }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default store;
```

Actually, these lines help me, without them I got above error:

```js
middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: {
    ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
  },
}),
```

Comment: This is consistent with the RTK docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist

Comment: I did the same thing but i get the same error.

Comment: @Dijiflex, I hope and pray your issue will be settled.

Comment: @Dijiflex same for me even after I re-start my local server, but somehow the warnings disappeared after several trials of restart.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @AmerllicA!! Sounds better than skipping all the actions with `serializableCheck: false`

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer for this issue. `serializableCheck: false` is just a bandaid. Instead, passing only the specific actions used by `redux-persist` is consistent with the redux toolkit docs and the correct (and specific) fix to the warning.

Comment: The FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, and REGISTER action types are all related to the redux-persist library, which is used to persist your Redux state between sessions. These actions are used internally by redux-persist and do not need to be serializable, which is why they are included in the ignoredActions array.

Answer (score 31):

This example shows excluding the serializable state check middleware [enter link description here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20goals%20of,checks%20for%20two%20common%20issues%3A&text=(Forked%20from%20redux%2Dimmutable%2Dstate%2Dinvariant%20.))

```
 const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
})
```

Answer (score 15):

Check the RTK docs on how to set it up with Redux Persist.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist

Basically it's just this line:

```
middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    })
```

Which is in the configureStore call.

Also, you need this:

```
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
```

Comment: And combining it with this another solution is even better https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15687#discussioncomment-45319

Answer (score 8):

I added 'middleWare' parameter with 'serializableCheck: false,'
problem solved. (it is not a problem actually)

source: [link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20goals%20of,checks%20for%20two%20common%20issues%3A&text=(Forked%20from%20redux%2Dimmutable%2Dstate%2Dinvariant%20.))

```
 import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    import rootReducer from './reducer'
    import { myCustomApiService } from './api'
    
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: rootReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: false,
        }),
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the following is the best option if you know exactly what it is that is non-serializable but that you need in the reducer anyway:

```js
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: { reducer },
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: ['TYPE'],
            ignoredActionPaths: ['property'],
            ignoredPaths: ['reducer.property']
        }
    })
});
```

For errors thrown in the action, either `ignoredActions` or `ignoredActionPaths` is enough. For errors thrown in the state, use `ignoredPaths`. Check the error message to see the names that you need to provide.

Just like @ReFruity , my issue appeared because I was keeping the `AbortController` there.

**EDIT:** Just an aside as, in order for the `AbortController` to work, I stored in the reducer just the `signal` and the `abort` method and I had to do this for it to work:

```js
let abortMethod = abortController.abort.bind(abortController);
```

Otherwise I was getting an error about illegal invocation.

Answer (score 3):

One of the core usage principles for Redux is that you should not put non-serializable values in state or actions.

However, like most rules, there are exceptions. However, if you do need to turnoff those warnings, you can customize the middleware by configuring it to ignore specific action types, or fields in actions and state:

```
configureStore({
  //...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: ['your/action/type'],  
      },
    }),
})
```

your/action/type should be replaced with actual action type which you will see in your warning message.

Reference: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data

Answer (score 3):

**I faced the kind of same error:**

[image]

**I was using the below versions and faced the same issue.**

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-redux": "^8.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"redux": "^4.2.1",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
```

I explored and got to know that the error message I am encountering suggests that there is a non-serializable value in an action object,
I applied the below solution and it is working.

```
// store.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

Answer (score 2):

This typically happens when you try to include non-serializable values, such as functions, in your Redux actions. Redux Toolkit's configureStore function includes a middleware

**Add middleware**:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: false,
        }),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know core use for Redux is that `you should not put non-serializable values in state or actions`.

But here we have an exceptions that there may be occasions when you have to deal with actions that `need to accept non-serializable data` but we need to make sure that these `non-serializable payloads shouldn't ever make it into your application state through a reducer`.

The serializability middleware will automatically warn anytime it detects non-serializable values in your actions or state. If you do need to turnoff those warnings, you can customize the middleware by configuring it to ignore specific action types, or fields in actions and state:

**Note:** It is recommended that to leave this middleware active to help avoid accidentally making mistakes.

```
configureStore({
  //...
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        // Ignore these action types
        ignoredActions: ['your/action/type'],
        // Ignore these field paths in all actions
        ignoredActionPaths: ['meta.arg', 'payload.timestamp'],
        // Ignore these paths in the state
        ignoredPaths: ['items.dates'],
      },
    }),
})
```

More Detailed Explanation:

1. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data
2. https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way

you can just add a middleWare and pass it to configureStore

```
import { rootReducer } from "./root-reducer";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import logger from "redux-logger";
const middleWares = [logger];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: middleWares,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
```

import these flush purge etc from redux-persist and add the middleware to configure store! The issue would be solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `axios` in your createAsyncThunk method just return response,

```
createAsyncThunk(
  "post/getPost",
  async ({ id }) => {
    return axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Typescripts classes with methods in it, you must use Javascript objects. This means:

Instead of using this:

```
const track1 = new Track("7empest", "TOOL", "Fear Inoculum", new Date(2024, 3, 2), 60 * 3);
```

You must use:

```
const track1 = { 
    title: "7empest", 
    artist: "TOOL", 
    album: "Fear Inoculum", 
    releaseDate: new Date(2024, 3, 2), 
    durationInSeconds: 60 * 3 
};
```