# How to overcome "A non-serializable value detection"

Tags: firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, redux-toolkit, redux-middleware

I'm implementing react app with redux-toolkit, and I get such errors when fetching data from firestore.

> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.0.timestamps.registeredAt`
>
> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.0.profile.location`.

The former's data type is [firebase.firestore.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), and the latter is [GeoPoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint?hl=en).

I think both might not be serializable, but I want to fetch those data and show them to users.
How can I overcome those errors?

According to [this issue](https://github.com/giantmachines/redux-websocket/issues/101), I might write like that;

```
const store = configureStore({
 reducer: rootReducer,
 middleware: [
  ...getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: {
     ignoredActionPaths: ['meta.arg', 'meta.timestamp'], // replace the left to my path
     },
  }),
  reduxWebsocketMiddleware,
 // ... your other middleware
],
});
```

But I'm not sure if it's safe and even if so, I don't know how to write the path dynamic way since my payload is array.

I'd really appreciate if anyone gives some clue.

Answer (score 11):

Check it out at

[Getting an error "A non-serializable value was detected in the state" when using redux toolkit - but NOT with normal redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704805/getting-an-error-a-non-serializable-value-was-detected-in-the-state-when-using)

accordingly with Rahad Rahman answer I did the follow in store.ts:

```
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        counter: counterReducer,
        searchShoes: searchShoesReducer,
    },    
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to go about this would be to convert that data into something serializable that you can safely store in your state.
According to the style guide, you [should not put Non-Serializable Values in State or Actions](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).

A good place to do that would be in a reducer [`prepare`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#customizing-generated-action-creators) function.