# under `async` function `useNavigate` not working nor throwing any error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, redux-toolkit

I do not know, some reason, `useNavigate` not working with following code:  any one help to use the `useNavigate` under the `async` function?

```
export const loginAdminUser = createAsyncThunk('post/login', async (user: UserLoginProps) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();//if i remove works
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(environment.BASE_URL + '/user/admin-login', user);
    console.log('response', response);
    if (response.data.success) {
      toast.success(response.data.message);
      toast('Redirecting to Home page');
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.data);
      navigate('/admin/home'); //trying to navigate page
    } else {
      toast.error(response.data.message);
    }
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    const err = error as AxiosError;
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: You can't use hooks in function. Only in function components or in other hooks.

Comment: How to handle this senarii

Comment: Pass navigate as a prop to createAsyncThunk callback `async ({user, navigate}) => {...}`

Comment: The better way is do navigate after fetching. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522295/passing-usenavigate-object-to-async-handler?noredirect=1&lq=1.