# How to format this date Timestamp(seconds=1676238124, nanoseconds=838000000) in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, timestamp, format

Im fetching some data from firestore, the date fields are in the format of `{seconds: XXXXX, nanoseconds: XXXXX}`. React Native complains about this saying this format is not a serializable value so to those fields I do this:

`docData.createdAt.toLocaleString()`

That gives me dates in the following format:

Timestamp(seconds=13223213, nanoseconds=12312312)

When I want to render those date fields with a human format like ISOString or LocaleDateString or anything it doesnt let me.

I've tried to do `new Date(createdAt)` but that gives me NaN.
I've also tried `createdAt.toDate() | createdAt.toISOString()` it doesnt recognize the functions.
I've also tried Timestamp.fromDate(createdAt) but it doesnt work either.

I want to get my dates in a human reading format like DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss

Here some pieces of code:

[Fetching data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVQc1.png)
[Some of my attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJJvV.png)

I'd like to have some hints or ideas or how to approach this issue.

Comment: To create a *Date* in POJS it would be `new Date(seconds * 1e3 + nanoseconds / 1e6)`. From there it's just [formatting a *Date*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date).

Comment: The thing is a that point, the format "Timestamp(seconds, nanoseconds) was not an object so I couldn't do something like "date.seconds

Comment: How you extracted the values for seconds and nanoseconds was entirely up to you. It seems the issue wasn't about parsing anyway.

Comment: Technically it is, because if I didn't set to false the serializable check I'd be with the same issue, getting a date the format I specified in the question. But thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the above answer works, this is what I did:

The issue was caused because of the SerializableCheck from redux [https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware] so I decided to set this middleware to false so It won't cause this error.

This is a StackOverFlow question about this topic that I found [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704805/getting-an-error-a-non-serializable-value-was-detected-in-the-state-when-using]

[image]

Now, about the date formats I did some changes:

Having disabled the serializeCheck option, now I can use .toDate() functions

[image]

Now wherever I need a date in a specific format I simply use a global function that receives two params: `date & format` and using `momentJS` the rest is easy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

****we can use this format  ..... work for me ****

```
import moment from 'moment';  <--- import this line 

const timestamp = 1676238124;
const nanoseconds = 838000000;


const Date = moment.unix(timestamp).add(nanoseconds / 1000000, 'milliseconds');
const Fordate = Date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
console.warn(Fordate)
```