# Save function instead of value in React, RTK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How to save a function instead of a value in RTK so that i can save a function reference in a component and call it in another component in React?

I just want to reset timer from another component. I don't know what to do so i made a state in react for that function reference

**HOME COMPONENT**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import { useIdleTimer } from "react-idle-timer";
import { userLogout } from "../utils/utils";
import LoadingAnimation from "../components/LoadingAnimation/LoadingAnimation";
import { setLogoutTimerReset } from "../store/slicers/logoutSlice";

const Home = () => {
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const onIdle = () => {
        userLogout();
    };

    const { reset } = useIdleTimer({
        onIdle,
        timeout: 60 * 30 * 1000, //60 minute idle timeout
        // timeout: 30000_000,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setLogoutTimerReset(reset));

        return () => {};
    }, []);

    return user ? (
        <section className="home-sidebar-flex">
            <Sidebar />

            <main className="map-main-parent--container">
                <Outlet />
            </main>
        </section>
    ) : (
        <LoadingAnimation />
    );
};

export default Home;
```

**SOME OTHER COMPONENT**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function App() {
  const { resetLogoutTimer } = useSelector((state) => state.logoutState);

  return (
    <div onClick={resetLogoutTimer}>Resetter</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**SLICE CODE**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    resetLogoutTimer: () => {},
};

export const logoutSlice = createSlice({
    name: "logout",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setLogoutTimerReset: (state, payload) => {
            state.resetLogoutTimer = payload;
        },
    },
});

export const {  setLogoutTimerReset } = logoutSlice.actions;

export default logoutSlice.reducer;
```

Reset idleTime from another component
I am using react-idle-timer

Answer (score 0):

> How to save a function instead of a value in RTK so that i can save a function reference in a component and call it in another component in React?

Personally I wouldn't recommend it since this is what for redux or context were created. You can move your logic there and just call it anywhere among your application.

However if you really insist on keeping your solution, I believe you are missing the `dispatch`.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setLogoutTimerReset(reset));

    return () => {};
}, []);
```

Comment: then what should i do
i am getting this error

A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `logoutState.resetLogoutTimer.payload`. Value: t => A.current ? !1 : (x(), V(), ue.current = v(), F.current += v() - w.current, te.current += v() - w.current, F.current = 0, h.current = !1, E.current = !1, H.current = !1, S.current = 0, N.current… 
Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: baseApi/subscriptions/internal_probeSubscription.

Comment: its still not working
i am getting same error
I have edited my question. i forgot to share slice code

Comment: @MubasherMukhtar Just disable the `serializableCheck`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704805/getting-an-error-a-non-serializable-value-was-detected-in-the-state-when-using

Comment: i did that but that didn't work
@Drew was correct i saved the whole object. but that worked only for Home's child component. If i call that function in Home's parent that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the *entire* action object in the state instead of just the reset function, a.k.a. the `action.payload`. In other words, `resetLogoutTimer` in the other component isn't the reset function, `resetLogoutTimer.payload` is.

Update the reducer function from

```js
setLogoutTimerReset: (state, payload) => { // <-- payload is action object!
  state.resetLogoutTimer = payload;
},
```

to

```js
setLogoutTimerReset: (state, action) => {
  state.resetLogoutTimer = action.payload;
},
```

Since it's preferable to store JSON *serializable* data in a Redux store you may also need to add/update the [Serializability Middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware) to handle the non-serializable function you are storing in the store.

Example:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  ...,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [setLogoutTimerReset],
        ignoredPaths: ["resetLogoutTimer"],
      },
    }),
});
```

This all said, it's actually preferable to just lift the `useIdleTimer` hook and `reset` function higher in the ReactTree to a common ancestor and pass down as a props or via a React Context to the descendent components that need it.

Comment: You are correct i saved the whole object. 
It worked only for Home's child component. If i call that function in Home's parent that doesn't work

Comment: @MubasherMukhtar Sorry, what function are you saying you are calling in the components? Are you referring to the dispatch of the `setLogoutTimerReset` action? Or trying to call the "reset" function that was stored in state? If you still need help with this then perhaps you could try standing up a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that we could inspect live and debug, which would be beneficial.